# Where and when is InitializeComponent called in Windows Forms control in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm doing a Windows Forms project in VB.NET, but VB.NET is completely new to me, I'm primarily a C# developer.

In C# Windows Forms, a user control's InitializeComponent is called from the form's/control's constructor. When I create same scenario in VB.NET I don't get a constructor, and I can't locate a place where InitializeComponent is called.

I need to call my code between InitializeComponent and when the control's `Load` event is raised, preferably still in the control's constructor. How do I do this in VB.NET?

Comment: The constructor is in your .Designer.vb file by default.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go to View Code in your form, and from the right drop down and select "New Method".

There you can see where InitializeComponent is called and insert your logic.

Your code, if your form is empty, should look like this:

```
Public Class Form1

    Public Sub New()
        ' This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: What about if the New() sub is missing? is InizializaComponents() called anywat by default as first thing in the super New() sub?

Comment: the compiler is going to create one for you(New()), the default one calls InitializeComponent anyways for you. It's a good practice though to have the above defined anyways as it guarantees order of execution of InitializeComponent

Answer (score 1):

In VB.NET the constructor is called `New` and has the following basic signature.

```
Public Sub New()
End Sub
```

You can of course override it and add custom parameters.

Visual Studio 2008, BTW, will remind you to put the `InitializeComponent()` method in the constructor in case you forget, as omitting that will lead to strange behaviors of your controls.