# Object reference not set to an instance of an object c# opening new form

Tags: c#

1. Ask user for username and password
2. On click button it checks the database connected for this username and password,
3. When correct it stores it's ID number in a variable, by default this variable is 0.
4. Then I run a If-statement, if the ID is >= 0, it needs to open another form. if not it displays Error message.

MessageBox in first If case displays the correct ID (1,2,3 whatever)
Now then on Form3, just a simple textbox1.text = "hi"; gives me the error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object c#. and it displays the textbox line.

```
    int IDnumber = 0;

        SqlCommand dataCommand = new SqlCommand(" SELECT ID FROM leden WHERE [Username]='" + username_txt.Text + "' and [Password]='" + password_txt.Text + "'", SC);
        SC.Open();
        IDnumber = Convert.ToInt32(dataCommand.ExecuteScalar());
        SC.Close();

        if (IDnumber >= 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Logged in, welcome ID number:" + IDnumber, "test");
            Form3 f3 = new Form3(IDnumber);
            f3.Show();                 
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Wrong Username and/or Password");
        }

}
```

form3:

```
public Form3(int _IDnumber)
{
    int IDnumber = _IDnumber;
    textBox1.Text = "hi";
}
```

Of course the textbox is a test, to show that it doesn't matter what textbox I use, it just gives me this error.
Yes, I do still use unecrypted passwords, don't know how to do that yet

Comment: You need to make sure the InitializeComponent method has run prior to accessing the control on the form (Form3). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042706/where-and-when-is-initializecomponent-called-in-windows-forms-control-in-vb-net for example. Is textBox1 actually initialized in this method?

Comment: I know this is not answering your question, but concatenating a sql statement with unsanitized user input is a really bad idea.  Google 'sql injection' and use a parameterized query instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not initialized the components on your form yet.
add

```
InitializeComponent();
```

in the beginning of your contructor.

Comment: My gut tells me this is the issue. `Form3` custom constructor is missing the `InitializeComponent()` call.

Comment: it doesn't show the entire form3 editing text, but I have, only in another public form3, which is the same name, thatswhy it gives me the error, lol that simple, got it fixed:
 public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Form3(int _IDnumber)
        {

            int IDnumber = _IDnumber;
            textBox1.Text = "hi";

        }

Comment: @RageCompex You need it in the beginning of all your constructors or call the base constructor

Comment: i was also thinking what could be the reason he is seeing exception, but no reached that..good job..:)

Answer (score 0):

Setting controls in a Forms constructor is not a wise idea, instead implement these things in the `OnLoad` event.

MSDN: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/360kwx3z(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/360kwx3z%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), you don't want to put code in constructor, use OnLoad.

Comment: down voter, that is absolutely a correct statement. I have experienced that many time, and of course the InitializeComponent() method was there.

Comment: Correct statement != Correct answer to the question at hand. This is more of a style choice, you can find [different](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860609) [opinions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623808) on where to put initialization logic.

Comment: This answer is irrelevant because it is not answering the question.

Comment: This is true however this is not the reason for getting the error.

Comment: I am not saying that the InitializeComponent() isn't the cause, i'm surprised it wasn't there.

Comment: guys, i need these points or else my child will be taken from me...  ?